# OCaml - Reading from file and splitting on character

Tags: split, stream, ocaml

I'm trying to read from a file in OCaml and break each line into a list of strings delimited by spaces and then append that list to a cumulative list.  The error I'm receiving is:

`File "bin/scanner.ml", line 17, characters 25-42:
Error: This expression has type string list
       but an expression was expected of type unit`

My entire program (scanner.ml) is:

```
  1 let tokens = [];;
  2 
  3 let split_spaces line =
  4     (String.split_on_char ' ' line) @ tokens;
  5     ;;
  6 
  7 (* Read input from an external file *)
  8 let line_stream_of_channel channel =
  9     Stream.from
 10         (fun _ ->
 11             try Some (input_line channel) with End_of_file -> None)
 12     ;;
 13 
 14 let in_channel = open_in "./input_files/test.c" in
 15     try
 16         Stream.iter
 17             (fun line -> split_spaces line)
 18         (line_stream_of_channel in_channel);
 19         close_in in_channel
 20     with e ->
 21         close_in in_channel;
 22         raise e
 23     ;;
```

I think I understand that the error is that split_space returns a list of strings while the anonymous function in line 17 expects a function returning type unit.  What I am stuck on is how I can modify split_spaces so that its return type is unit.

Answer (score 1):

A function that returns unit is an imperative-style function that does something for its side effect and doesn't return a useful value.

If your functions all return unit, how will you accumulate your list of words?

In fact I don't see this cumulative list of words anywhere in your code.

The fact is you probably want to go the other way. You want to replace `Stream.iter`, which is an imperative function with side effects. Instead you most likely want your own function that calls `Stream.next` and returns an accumulated value (rather than unit).